# Test RMSE of polynomial regression drops when using more variables?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, supervised-learning, model-selection

I am testing polynomial regression for a data set of 50 variables and a sample size of 5000. I ordered the coefficients of the linear model from high to low and then made different models using the **p** most explanatory variables. The RMSE values of these models are shown in the following figures. For polynomial regression of degree=2 everything seems to be normal, but for degree=3 something strange happens. (The dotted line shows the location of minimum RMSE)

[image: Comparison of RMSE in polynomial regression of degree 2]
[image: Comparison of RMSE in polynomial regression of degree 3]

I cannot understand why the test RMSE drops when using more than 27 variables? It seems to start underfitting rather than overfitting with more variables. Interestingly, this happens at the same time as the training RMSE becomes around 1e-14. Meanwhile, the adjused R-squared shows the following strange behaviour at that moment:

[image: Comparison of adjusted R2 in polynomial regression of degree 3]

Am I using just too many dimensions for this polynomial regression? Or is there another reason why this is happening? I would love to understand what is going on. I will quickly move on to better algorithms, but I just wanted to make a benchmark for my ML project. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The cubics tend to explode, especially with data that has not been seen in the training set. Also, multicorrelations between variables are more likely, if all variables are cubed in your model.

Comment: If the cubics explode, wouldn't the learning algorithm just assign 0 to their coefficients? I still do not get why the test error decreases by learning more features.

Comment: Learning algorithm is learning only on your training set, and you can see that RMSE is OK when training, but explodes when testing. So if the results are fine when training - the algorithm doesn't see the need to assign 0 for the coefficients. High test errors that you are seeing indicates a poorly selected model when in training (in other words, a possible overfit - though my guess would still be an exploded third power). Did you try plotting fitted vs actual values for both good models and the one that has large RMSE?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I understand that high test errors are caused by an overfit model, but the part I cannot wrap my head around is something else. By _increasing_ the amount of variables that we are using in the model (see figure 2 in the original post) the testing error first blows up and then becomes normal again. Why doesn't it keep blowing up?

Comment: I don't think it becomes _normal_, as in the RMSE is still higher than when using 1 variable (from what I can tell from the graph), but I get your point. Did you try analyzing/plotting the specific models? Do you get the same RMSE results when bootstrapping your  sample or shuffling between different train/test samples?